# Symfony 2 removes factory services?

Tags: exception, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

Does Symfony automatically remove factory services?

Don't know what's going on, but my bundle is correctly loading `service.xml` file:

```xml
<services>
    <service id="gremo_subscription_factory"
        class="%gremo_subscription_factory.class%" public="false">
        <argument>%gremo_subscription.interval%</argument>
    </service>
    <service id="gremo_subscription" class="%gremo_subscription.class%"
        factory-service="gremo_subscription_factory"
        factory-method="getSubscription">
    </service>
</services>
```

This is done by the extension class:

```php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $processor = new Processor();
    $configuration = new Configuration();

    $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

The definition for services `gremo_subscription_factory` exists (`var_dump` the container shows the service definition) in the bundle. However when I try to access `gremo_subscription` service (from a controller, for example) from another bundle:

```php
$subscription = $this->get('gremo_subscription');
```

I get the exception:

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   "gremo_subscription_factory".

Why this is happening?

Comment: You need a reference to the service, so you need an `@` in front of `gremo_subscription_factory`

Comment: @Squazic nope, there is no need for the @. The problem is public=false...

Comment: My bad, I usually use yaml and not xml, so thought that was the problem. It seems you're not following the method [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) use to define factory services. Try mirroring that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `gremo_subscription_factory` as private.

Remove the `public="false"` flag on the service.